# Firebase cloud functions triggered by new json data(served on url)

Tags: json, flutter, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

My question is if there is a way to trigger google cloud functions when a new data is added to the json file served with a url? If it is possible, i thought that i could write a cloud function that always listens to the json url and when an update is made maybe save that new data to the firebase database and push it to the users of the flutter app as a notification or without saving it just directly push it to the users of the flutter app as a notification.
I appreciate any help.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions cannot trigger on changes at just any URL.

The two closest equivalents I can think of:

- Store the JSON file in Cloud Storage, and [trigger your Cloud Function on writes to that](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events).
- Store the JSON in Firebase's Realtime Database, which is a JSON data structure already, and [trigger your Cloud Functions on writes to that](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, the json that is served on url works realtime based on a mysql database. Im curious if any of your methods would ve realtime too in this case? If so i will try it ASAP.

Comment: My question may be silly but i would be really thankful for an idea from you. Would i maybe need a webserver that can communicate with FCM that always triggers it whenever an update is made on the server?

Comment: I answered the question you posted as best as I can. If you have a new question based about your broader use-case, I recommend opening a new question for that.